# Error when trying to convert Python/Kivy file to apk using buildozer

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk, buildozer

I was using buildozer on Ubuntu for Windows 10. About 8 minutes into the debugging process, I'm getting an error saying buildozer couldn't execute my last command. I'm posting the logline that showed up right before the error, let me know if something else is needed. I followed this Youtube video (using the included sample files) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzsvN3fuBA0 still not sure what's causing the error though.

```
>     [DEBUG]:        checking for aarch64-linux-android-gcc... /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
> -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC          [DEBUG]:        checking whether the C compiler works... no                                                           
> [DEBUG]:        configure: error: in
> `/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
> [DEBUG]:        configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> [DEBUG]:        See `config.log' for more details                     
> Exception in thread background thread for pid 20270:                  
> Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in
> _bootstrap_inner                                                   self.run()                                                            
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run             
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)                             
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in
> wrap                                                fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in
> background_thread                                  
> handle_exit_code(exit_code)                                           
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in
> fn                                                  return
> self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)                      
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in
> handle_command_exit_code                             raise exc        
> sh.ErrorReturnCode_77:                                                
> RAN:
> /root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure
> --host=aarch64-linux-android --prefix=/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared                                                                                                                                                                       STDOUT:                                                               
> checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu                     
> checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android            
> checking target system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android          
> checking for gsed... sed                                              
> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c          
> checking whether build environment is sane... yes                     
> checking for aarch64-linux-android-strip...
> /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip
> --strip-unneeded                                                                            checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p                
> checking for gawk... gawk                                             
> checking whether make -j4 sets $(MAKE)... yes                         
> checking whether make -j4 supports nested variables... yes            
> checking for aarch64-linux-android-gcc...
> /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
> -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC                          checking whether the C compiler works... no                                                           
> configure: error: in
> `/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables                
> See `config.log' for more details                                     
> STDERR:                                                               
> Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main 
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,                            
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code            
> exec(code, run_globals)                                               
> File
> "/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 1262, in <module>                                                
> main()                                                                
> File
> "/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py",
> line 18, in main                                                      
> ToolchainCL()                                                         
> File
> "/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 680, in __init__                                                 
> getattr(self, command)(args)                                          
> File
> "/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 99, in wrapper_func                                              
> build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)                                 
> File
> "/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 158, in build_dist_from_args                                     
> build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,                       
> File
> "/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py",
> line 504, in build_recipes                                            
> recipe.build_arch(arch)                                               
> File
> "/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py",
> line 30, in build_arch                                                
> shprint(sh.Command('./configure'),                                    
> File
> "/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py",
> line 167, in shprint                                                  
> for line in output:                                                   
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in
> next                                                 self.wait()      
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in
> wait                                                
> self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)                              
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in
> handle_command_exit_code                             raise exc        
> sh.ErrorReturnCode_77:                                                
> RAN:
> /root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure
> --host=aarch64-linux-android --prefix=/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared                                                                                                                                                                       STDOUT:                                                               
> checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu                     
> checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android            
> checking target system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android          
> checking for gsed... sed                                              
> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c          
> checking whether build environment is sane... yes                     
> checking for aarch64-linux-android-strip...
> /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip
> --strip-unneeded                                                                            checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p                
> checking for gawk... gawk                                             
> checking whether make -j4 sets $(MAKE)... yes                         
> checking whether make -j4 supports nested variables... yes            
> checking for aarch64-linux-android-gcc...
> /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
> -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC                          checking whether the C compiler works... no                                                           
> configure: error: in
> `/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables                
> See `config.log' for more details                                     
> STDERR:                                                               
> Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m',
> 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=kivy_example',
> '--bootstrap=sdl2',
> '--requirements=python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4,kivy_garden.graph,numpy',
> '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs',
> '--color=always',
> '--storage-dir=/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']                       
> ENVIRONMENT:                                                          
> SHELL = '/bin/bash'                                                   
> WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'                                            
> NAME = 'LAPTOP-6NQEQL39'                                              
> PWD = '/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main/graphs'    
> 
>      LOGNAME = 'root'                                                                                                       HOME = '/root'                                                        
> LANG = 'C.UTF-8'                                                      
> LS_COLORS =
> 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'                                #     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'                                                                             #     TERM = 'xterm-256color'                                                                                           #     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'                                                                               #     USER = 'root'                                                                                                     #     SHLVL = '1'                                                                                                       #     WSLENV = ''                                                                                                           XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'  
> 
>      PATH = ('/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program
> '                                                                 
> 'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_2204.2.33.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program
> '                             'Files (x86)/IVI '                      
> 'Foundation/VISA/WinNT/Bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Users/samar/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/samar/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/mnt/c/Users/samar/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin')
> #     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'                                                                                               #     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'                                                                                    #     OLDPWD = '/root/sdfdsfd/kivy_examples-main/kivy_examples-main'                                                    #     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'                                                               #     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'                                                      #     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'                  
> #     ANDROIDAPI = '30'                                                                                                 #     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'                                                                                              #                                                                                                                       # Buildozer failed to execute the last command                                                                          # The error might be hidden in the log above this error                                                                 # Please read the full log, and search for it before                                                                    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.                                                                               # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Have you read the error log, especially the line `C compiler cannot create executables. See 'config.log' for more details`? And have you checked `config.log` for details?